# Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager' not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composer-php, vendor

Im follow phpacademys new authentication tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF2WkRCZfBg

i have a class file database.php:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
 'driver'     => $app->config->get('db.driver'),
 'host'       => $app->config->get('db.host'),
 'database'   => $app->config->get('db.name'),
 'username'   => $app->config->get('db.username'),
 'password'   => $app->config->get('db.password'),
 'charset'    => $app->config->get('db.charset'),
 'collation'  => $app->config->get('db.collation'),
 'prefix'     => $app->config->get('db.prefix')
]);

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

however it throws up this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\boilerplate\app\database.php on line 4

i have required it in start.php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
//############ NAMESPACING ################//
use Slim\Slim; //import slim
use Noodlehaus\Config;
use Boilerplate\User\User;
//#########################################//

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors','on'); //TURN OFF ON LIVE SITE

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__)); //create local root

require INC_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // autoload in all the      dependencies in the vendor files.

$app = new Slim([
'mode' => file_get_contents(INC_ROOT . '/mode.php')
]); //assign the entire app file to a variable

$app->configureMode($app->config('mode'), function() use ($app){
$app->config = Config::load(INC_ROOT . "/app/config/{$app->mode}.php"); //pull in the config file
});

$app->container->set('user', function(){
    return new User;
});
```

Comment: Are you pulling in Illuminate\Database using composer ?

Comment: yes i am this is my json file {
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Boilerplate\\" : "app/Boilerplate"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2",
        "hassankhan/config": "0.8.*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.0",
        "illuminate/database": "~5.0",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "~1.1"
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've added `Illuminate\Database` to you're composer file and run `composer update`

Then put `require 'database.php';` after you're adding the autoloader

```
require INC_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Below here
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude literally be racking my brain for a day!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case the solution was to install composer again with the next command:

```
composer install
```

If you are using docker, make sure that you are inside the container before run the install command.

```
docker-compose run <app_name> bash
```